# Restful, How to create a dynamic facade for URI to PHP class Methods without routing in the code

Tags: php, rest, restful-url

I've looking for a way to map many methods and many URI's but the API propose is to map every URL in the code.

I'm working on https://github.com/Respect/Rest and I've used the catch all parameters option to use any url for example:

```
$objRest = new Rest('/myurl_base');    
$objRest->post('/*/**', function($resource, $arrSubResources)
    {
        $resource::post_method($arrSubResources, $_POST);
    });
```

But the problem is that sometimes I need to call an URL with a name that is not the same of class name and is not useful for client implementation to use the class names I called.

Any suggestion?

- Could be an advanced API to get it or any practice you've seen.

Considerations

- I prefer not to touch the routing code file for every URL.
- Every method in any class could be a resource for a URL.
- The URL could contains dynamic parameters.
- There is a big developer team to create many methods every day.

Thanks for your help.